# How to show a full-screen ad (like Flixster) randomly in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ads

I have recently started programming in iOS. I found this really interesting way of showing an Ad in the Flixster app. It randomly pops up a latest movie banner and asks to watch trailer or skip to continue using the app. How is it actually implemented? how can they be pushing a variable screen (may be a view) at runtime? Every time you open the app, you see a different banner.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Flixster and here's how we do it:

Every time the app starts or resumes, the app pings our API to ask for what ads should be shown.  Our api gives our app the url of the image to be shown, as well as the click-through url, which can be a regular url, or a custom link to one of our native pages like viewing a trailer, or a movie info page.

We have an admin tool where we can upload the ad image, modify the properties of the ads, or remove old ads and add new ads.  However, we've recently started using 3rd party Ad networks like DFP and Admob (acquired by Google) to take over this management.